# How to change the menu and context menu's themes?

Tags: android, api, menu, colors, edit

I'm making an Android application with a normal and floating context menu, but its background is white, and when I click on it, the selection color is the default orange of olders Android versions.

My application is a black/blue themed, but this orange is ruining it.
The AndroidManifest.xml is set to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

Does it influences somehow?

How can I set the blue themed menus of the latest versions of Android (e.g. ICS/JB)?

Comment: check this http://actionbarsherlock.com/